# Uploaded image does not display using 'out.print' in JSP page

Tags: java, image, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to add some simple user image upload functionality to my webpage. At the moment I have (as far as I can tell) a working image upload - when I upload an image, it appears in the correct folder in my web app directory. However, I try to display the image on the page once the user uploads but for some reason it doesn't appear, even thought the page source looks correct...

In the jsp file I use the code

```
                FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
                if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
                    // Get the uploaded file parameters
                    String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                    String fileName = fi.getName();
                    boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                    long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                    // Write the file
                    if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
                        file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                    }
                    else {
                        file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                    }
                    fi.write( file ) ;
                    out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fileName + "<br></br>");
                    out.println("<img src = \"uploads/" + fileName + "\"></img>");
```

When I upload an image, the page displays "Uploaded Filename:..." but not the image. If I view page source I can also see the line of code referring to the image, and if I click on the image source "uploads/photo.png", the photo opens up in a new browser page. I have no clue why I can't display it - I have also tried changing the path but it seems like this should be the correct one...

My folder structure is:
webapps
  root
    index.jsp
    upload.jsp
    uploads
      photo.png

Is this a problem with Tomcat (I am using Tomcat 7) or with the way I am using the jsp page or the filepath? If anyone has any clues it would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding these two lines to the top of the html file produced by the jsp:

```
out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
out.println("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the image tag is not right.  Img tag is self-closing (`<img />`) not two parts (`<img></img>`).

```
out.println("<img src='uploads/" + fileName + "' />");
```

I changed the `\"` to just `'` to make it easier to read. HTML can use single-quotes for attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but still the same result! If I view page source I see this:

<html>
<head>
<title>JSP File upload</title>
</head>
<body>
Uploaded Filename: /Applications/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/uploads/pic.jpg<br></br>
<img src='uploads/pic.jpg' />
</body>
</html>

and if I click on pic.jpg the picture opens up in a new window - but isn't being displayed on the page :/